# Swift: UIStackView height is always 0 despite adding elements

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, tvos, uistackview

I have this stack view, it contains one ImageView:
[image]
If I print its height, I always get 0:

```
  print("movieDetailsStackView!.bounds.height: ",movieDetailsStackView!.bounds.height ) // 0
    print("movieDetailsStackView!.frame.height: ",movieDetailsStackView!.frame.height ) // 0
```

This is how it's created:

```
func createMovieDetailsStackView () {
    /******************/
    // Add movie image
    /*****************/
    let movieImageViewHeight = 300.00
    let movieImageViewWidth = 20.00
    movieImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: movieImageViewWidth, height: movieImageViewHeight));
    movieImageView!.layer.borderWidth = 10
    movieImageView!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    /******************/
    var arrangedSubviews = [UIView]()
    arrangedSubviews.append(movieImageView!)
    
    movieDetailsStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrangedSubviews)
    
    movieDetailsStackView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    movieDetailsStackView!.distribution = .fillProportionally
    movieDetailsStackView!.axis = .horizontal
    movieDetailsStackView!.spacing = 8

    self.view.addSubview(movieDetailsStackView!)

    movieDetailsStackView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant:70).isActive = true
    movieDetailsStackView!.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    movieDetailsStackView!.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    
}
```

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a height constraint to the stack view as well? one that is equal to the movieImageViewHeight

Answer (score 1):

When you add any view as an `arrangedSubview` of a stack view, its `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property is automatically set to `false.

So, depending on how you have your stack view's Alignment and Distribution properties set, you may need to add Width and/or Height constraints to the view.

You have some odd settings in the code you've shown, for example:

- `let movieImageViewWidth = 20.00` ... do you really want it to be only 20-pts wide?
- `movieDetailsStackView!.distribution = .fillProportionally` ... that is almost certainly ***NOT*** what you want for distribution. Start with `.fill` and only change that if you're not getting the desired result.
- you're using a lot of `!` ... "force unwrapping" is a recipe for crashes.

However, with your existing code, add this line:

```
movieDetailsStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrangedSubviews)

// add this line here
movieImageView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(movieImageViewHeight)).isActive = true
```

and see if you get your desired result.